# A constant parameter in a three body system?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, flyby, calculation, three-body

In a two body system, there are a lot of orbital parameters not changing over time, like eccentricity or the orbital plane.

A constant parameter can be a combination of two or more, like even though kinetic and potential energy is always changing in an elliptical orbit, they always sum up to a constant energy.

Is there any equivalent parameter that does not change for the smaller satellite in a three body system? Can that parameter be used to confirm if you are observing the same asteroid after a fly-by of, let's say Jupiter?

Comment: fyi [Three-body versus CR3BP tags; combine them?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1345/12102)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the [Jacobi integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_integral) ($C_\text{J}$, or $C_\text{H}$ in [Hill's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_sphere)):

> In [celestial mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_mechanics), Jacobi's integral (also The Jacobi Integral or
>   The Jacobi Constant; named after [Carl Gustav Jacob Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Gustav_Jacob_Jacobi)) is the only
>   known conserved quantity for the [circular restricted three-body
>   problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_three-body_problem). Unlike in the two-body problem, the energy and momentum of
>   the system are not conserved separately and a general analytical
>   solution is not possible. The integral has been used to derive
>   numerous solutions in special cases.

For a worked example, as requested specifically about application of CRTBP conserved quantity for a Jupiter flyby (in this case a time-frequency analysis of a Sun-Jupiter-comet system), see e.g. [Time-frequency analysis of the restricted three body problem: Transport and resonance transitions](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/bib/2004/01-VeMa2004/VeMa2004.pdf), Luz V. Vela-Arevalo and Jerrold E. Marsden, Georgia Institute of Technology (PDF).

Comment: So that is what it is! Finally the universe is starting to make sense.

Comment: Is that the research which allowed the estimation of a comet impact into Jupiter latitude with about $\pm 180 ^{\circ}$ accuracy? :)

Comment: @SF. No. Latitudes only go to $\pm 90°$ :P

Answer (score 3):

There is another parameter known as Tisserand's parameter which stays constant for a given body in 3 body probelm. 
This is more useful in identifying any given asteroid or comet. 
Given by

$T = \dfrac{a_e}{a}+2\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{a_e}(1-e^2)}cos(i)$

where e subscript represents parameters of perturbing body and no subscript for small body. 
It stays constant for a body even after the close encounter and is very useful in identifying if a newly discovered asteroid is an old body that underwent close encounter.

http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node122.html